# Node merging for rating

Tags: rating

I want to ask if it is possible to "virtual" merge 2 different nodes created at 2 different timestamp but which contains the same node Title(only the "explain" text field is different)
I want to rate these nodes with the [Fiveestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module but the average has to be calculated from both of them. Now they are treated as 2 different nodes.

Is this possible?

Kind regards

Jürgen

Comment: Why don't you use one node, and simply show full view or excerpt where applicable?

Comment: Yes or.. , I think that working with rules to simply not allow 2 nodes with the same title will do the trick. right?

Comment: If simply disallowing 2 nodes with same title solves your problem, great - but it means I totally don't understand what your problem exactly is.

Comment: My bad, not enough specific in my question, sorry for that.